# Ajax receiving data type

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

How will Ajax accept data if the data type is `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`?

PS: I know that I will have to call the function in the url, I just don't know the data type and how can one display that data in an html table?

Comment: It depends on a lot of things, but if your server-side code is using WebAPI, then it can typically return either XML or JSON, depending on what is requested from the client. This will happen automatically, without you have to write any specific conversion code.

The decision as to JSON or XML is based on the incoming request, so when you make your Ajax request you can specify. JSON is usually the default if you don't.

Comment: So how can I display the data in an html table if the data type is json?

Comment: You'd have to write some JavaScript to loop through the data in the JSON and generate the appropriate table rows. You don't have to use JavaScript directly - you could use JQuery or something like Angular.

Comment: If your server-side code is python and this is sending a list data type, this can be used as an Array type in JavaScript. Data types are relevant to the language using the data in this situation.

Comment: Thankyou @jasper

Comment: @Jools no it's in c sharp and the data type is a combination of two data types the dictionary is nested in a list

Comment: @Ayesha1234 it should still be serialised into a useable format for JavaScript, probably either a string or array. But I see your real end goal is to place this data into a table. So Jasper's response is the way to do this, how you loop over it will depend on what value is in the JSON.

Comment: How should I predefine the json structure if my list has a dictionary nested in it? Do I have to declare the json object or not?